# SonataMediaBundle error

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.3

I use `Symfony2.3` for my project.

I configure SonataAdminBundle, SonataUserBundle following [this steps](http://tech.dupeu.pl/2013/07/symfony-2-3-sonataadminbundle-sonatamediabundle-sonatauserbundle-and-fosuserbundle-a-good-project-base/). After I configure and finish all steps, sonata admin and user bundle are working fine, but when i go to media in admin, i got the following error:

> No entity manager defined for class Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\Media 
>   500 Internal Server Error - RuntimeException

Thanks.